# How can I find the week which a day belongs to using javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, week-number

I want to find the number of the week which a day belongs to in javascript. My definition of week is the number of saturdays there have been up to that date. So the first few days of january are counted as the final week of the previous year. From there, the first saturday to the preceding friday is week 0 (0 based week counting).

Anyone know how to implement a function like this?

Comment: The first thing required to implement such a function is effort.  You provide no evidence that you've applied any whatsoever.  Why anybody would actually provide you with answers is beyond me, and then you have the gall to nitpick them

Comment: I have applied effort, but none of my attempts succeeded. And I'm not nitpicking, I'm just saying that the solutions aren't solving the issue. Sorry if I've made it seem that way.

Comment: @George: The SO community has slightly different angle on the requirement for effort here than you might find on a straightforward NG or Forum. A good and accepted answer doesn't go entirely without reward. Secondly the objective of SO is to be __the__ place to quickly find an answer to a question.   So a searcher need not even have put the effort in to ask the question because someone else already has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This?

```
function week(date) {
    var firstSat = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    firstSat.setDate(firstSat.getDate() + (6 - firstSat.getDay()));

    var delta = Math.floor((date - firstSat) / (7*24*60*60*1000));

    return delta < 0 ?
           delta + 52 : // first few days before 1st Sat
           delta
}

week(new Date(2009,0,1)); // Jan 1, 2009 => 51 => "1 week into last year"
week(new Date(2009,0,2)); // 51
week(new Date(2009,0,3)); // 0 => "[beginning of] week 1"
week(new Date(2009,0,10)); // 1 => "[beginning of] week 2"
week(new Date(2009,0,11)); // 1 => "still week 2"
week(new Date(2009, 9, 30)); // Fri Oct 30, 2009 => 42
```

Comment: Very close. However, I need "1 week into last year" to return 51 or 52, as it should count from the previous year's weeks

Comment: Thanks. Minor (but probably unimportant) point: most years only have 52 weeks (0-based: 51), but that should be fine for the use I intend.

Comment: @Eric: you're right. Further, rounding up (i.e. "Saturdays == end of week") means you will get 52 at the tail end of the year also. Adjusted code to always round down (i.e. "Saturdays == start of *new* week")

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [**http://www.datejs.com/**](http://www.datejs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var getWeekForDate = function(date) {
  var yearStart = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0);

  // move to first Saturday
  yearStart.setDate(yearStart.getDate() + (6 - yearStart.getDay()));

  var msSinceStart = date - yearStart;
  var daysSinceStart = msSinceStart / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  var weeksSinceStart = daysSinceStart / 7;
  return Math.floor(weeksSinceStart);
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work on dates before the first saturday of the year. Instead of returning -1, as it does now, it should return 51 or 52, depending on the previous year

Comment: Because a client wants each week, defined as starting on saturday, to be a certain holiday season. The idea would be to calculate the week number, then pull the corresponding season from an array.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went for:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function()
{
 var localOffset = this.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
 var date = new Date(this-localOffset);
 var firstSat = new Date(this);
 firstSat.setDate(1);
 firstSat.setMonth(0);
 firstSat.setDate(firstSat.getDate() + (6 - firstSat.getDay()));

 if(date < firstSat)
 {
  date.setDate(date.getDate()-7);
  return date.getWeek()+1;
 }
 else
 {
  return Math.floor((date - firstSat) / (7*24*60*60*1000));
 }
}
```

Which removes problems with UTC offsets